# How do you set message properties in Mule using Groovy?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

How do you set message properties in Mule using Groovy?

I need to set a message property from within a Groovy Scripting Component.  Documentation on the subject does not appear to be easy to find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the scripting component you have available the message binding that is an instance of [org.mule.api.MuleMessage](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleMessage.html), thus you can use the method [org.mule.api.MuleMessage.addProperties(Map, PropertyScope)](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleMessage.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope%29) to add any property you need.

Answer (score 12):

You can set individual properties as follows:

```
message.setInvocationProperty('myFlowVariable', 'value') // sets a flow variable, like <set-variable/>
message.setOutboundProperty('myProperty', 'value') // sets an outbound message property, like <set-property/>
message.setProperty('myInboundProperty', 'value', PropertyScope.INBOUND) // sets an inbound property
```

Comment: I attempted something like the above, but got an error.  My Groovy script text looks like this: `message.setProperty('sourceConfig', payload, PropertyScope.OUTBOUND)
return payload;`  I got the following error:  `Root Exception stack trace:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: PropertyScope for class: Script4`

Comment: Sorry, I just needed to import PropertyScope in the script component.

Comment: @RyanHoegg To me this should be added to the answer  `import org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope`  .. thanks to you both

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which version of Mule EE (and so then Groovy) you are using, but in recent versions of Mule (3.7.x) the easiest way is:

```
flowVars ['name_of_variable'] = 'value'
flowVars ['name_of_variable'] = 14
```

This for variables with `Invocation` scope, if you wan to store variable for `Session` scope, then:

```
sessionVars ['name_of_variable'] = 'value'
sessionVars ['name_of_variable'] = 14
```

Please use this site from Mulesoft for Scripting as reference.

**https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/script-component-reference**

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I figured it out:

add schema to your flow if missing: 
xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd

now let's set session-variable 'account' with a custom Foo object using Groovy:

```
   <scripting:transformer doc:name="Script">
     <scripting:script engine="groovy"><![CDATA[  
        com.test.Foo f = new com.test.Foo();
        f.setAccountId('333');
        return message.setSessionProperty('account',f);]]>
      </scripting:script>
    </scripting:transformer>
```

above script will turn your Payload to NullPayload, because it is a transformer. If that' a concern, try this instead:

```
<enricher target="#[sessionVars['account']]">
   <scripting:transformer doc:name="Script">
     <scripting:script engine="groovy"><![CDATA[  
       com.test.Foo f = new com.test.Foo();
       f.setAccountId('333');
       return f;]]>
     </scripting:script>
   </scripting:transformer>
 </enricher>
```

Enjoy. :)